# Angular warning stack after the update from version 9 to 10. ngtypecheck.ts and Add only entry points ... in tsconfig

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-material

I just updated my angular version from 9 to 10.

I followed the below steps to do so. As per the Angular Update Guide

Step 1:

> ng update @angular/core @angular/cli

Step 2: Since I am using angular material. I updated the angular material as well.

> ng update @angular/material

Step 3: Last step.

> ng update

**My package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "my-app-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.12",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.12",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.12",
    "@angular/material": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.12",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.12",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  }
}
```

**My Angular version**

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.7
Node: 12.18.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.0.12
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: <error>

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.900.7
@angular-devkit/core              9.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.7
@angular/cdk                      10.1.3
@angular/cli                      10.0.7
@angular/flex-layout              10.0.0-beta.32
@angular/material                 10.1.3
@ngtools/webpack                  9.0.7
@schematics/angular               10.0.7
@schematics/update                0.1000.7
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.9.7
webpack                           4.41.2
```

**I got too many warnings like mentioned below.**

> WARNING in __local_path__file_name..ngtypecheck.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
> Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.

Also, tsconfig.app.json file as mentioned below

```
  {
          "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
          "compilerOptions": {
            "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
            "types": []
          },
          "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
          "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
    }
```

I tried several solutions. But nothing worked for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try to update tsconfig.app.json with

```
    {
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.prod.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

reference:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17066